# create a display alert function globally and call it from any view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

```
func displayalert(title:String, message:String, vc:UIViewController)
{
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    })))

    vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}


this is the function i have used.i tried to call it like this,

 displayalert1(title:"dsfvasdcs", message:"easfSDXCSDZX", vc:validateOTPViewController())
```

it is returning error "BAD ACCESS". the vc.present is running like a loop. I cant understand what the problem is.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Create this method as a static method and add its class in your project's .pch file. You will be able access it any class.

Comment: That's bad programming habit. Put the code in an extension of `UIViewController`, delete the `vc` parameter and delete `vc.` in the `present` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code and it working fine. I thing you would pass self in vc.

```
 self.displayalert(title: "Title", message: "Some Message", vc: self)
```

You can also make an extension of UIViewController-

```
   extension UIViewController {
          // Your Function...
    }
```

Now You can globally access this function from any view controller, Just by typing-

```
    self.displayalert(title: "Title", message: "Some Message", vc: self)
```

Comment: You can also make an extension of UIViewController and put your function there, So that you can globally access this function from any view controller, Just by typing-     self.displayalert(title: "Title", message: "Some Message", vc: self)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a new instance of the `validateOTPViewController` to the `displayalert` function.

Change it to:

```
displayalert1(title:"dsfvasdcs", message:"easfSDXCSDZX", vc:self)
```

This will pass the current view controller to the function instead of a new one that hasn't been presented.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

Create an extension of `UIViewController` with your function to display alert with required parameter arguments

```
extension UIViewController {

      func displayalert(title:String, message:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        })))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


      }
}
```

Now call this function from your view controller:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.displayalert(title: <String>, message: <String>)
    }
}
```